# GSAP staggerFrom negative delay

Tags: javascript, gsap

**Question:**

I am wondering if there is a way to add a negative delay to the `staggerFrom` / `staggerTo` functions in greensock?

**Problem:**

I have animation is running too long for my liking. It would be great if my staggered animations could happen as the previous animations are playing to cut down the duration.

**Example:**

I have put together this codepen to illustrate what I am after: http://codepen.io/nickspiel/pen/LpepvQ?editors=001

You can see in the codepen that I have used negative delays on the basic `from` timeline functions but this doesn't work for the `staggerForm` function as the delay parameter is used to delay each element of the jquery collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this same question on the [Greensock GitHub repo](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/issues/124) and had the following response:

> Absolutely - that's already baked in. I'm not sure if you're using
>   TweenMax or one of the timeline classes, so I'll show you both:

```
TweenMax.staggerTo(elements, 1, {x:100, delay:2}, 0.01);

// - OR -

var tl = new TimelineLite();
tl.staggerTo(elements, 1, {x:100, delay:2}, 0.01);

// - OR -

var tl = new TimelineLite(); 
tl.staggerTo(elements, 1, {x:100}, 0.01, "label+=3");
```

In my case the last option worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the new **[`cycle`](http://greensock.com/gsap-1-18-0)** property introduced in the latest **v1.18.0** of GSAP?

So you can *cycle* with `delay` but passing `0` as `stagger` value in the `staggerTo` calls.

Also, you can pass `position` parameter to `staggerTo` calls to make them overlap with the previously inserted tween.

**[Here](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/yYpOdw?editors=001)** is the forked pen for an idea.

**JavaScript:**

```
...
animateElement = function() {
        timeline.from(main, 0.3, { scaleY: '0%', ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) })
        .staggerFrom(dataBlocks, 0.3, { cycle: { delay: function(index) {
            return index * 0.1;
        }}, scale: '0%', y: 100, ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, 0)
        .from(lineGraphLines, 1.5, { drawSVG: 0, ease: Power1.easeOut }, '-=0.5')
        .from(lineGraphAreas, 1, { opacity: 0, ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, '-=2.0')
        .staggerFrom(lineGraphDots, 0.2, { cycle: { delay: function(index) {
            return index * 0.1;
        }}, scale: 0, ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, 0, '-=1.0')
        .staggerFrom(donutCharts, 0.6, { cycle: { delay: function(index) {
            return index * 0.1;
        }}, drawSVG: 0, ease: Power1.easeOut }, 0, '-=2.0')
        .from(menuBackground, 0.3, { scaleX: '0%', ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, '-=6')
        .staggerFrom(menuElements, 0.3, { cycle: { delay: function(index) {
            return index * 0.1;
        }}, scaleX: '0%', ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, 0, '-=1')
        .from(headerBackground, 0.5, { scaleX: '0%', ease: Power1.easeOut }, '-=5.5')
        .staggerFrom(headerBoxes, 0.3, { cycle: { delay: function(index) {
            return index * 0.1;
        }}, scale: '0%', ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, 0, '-=1.0')
        .staggerFrom(headerText, 0.4, { cycle: { delay: function(index) {
            return index * 0.1;
        }}, scaleX: '0%', ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, 0, '-=1.0')
        .from(headerText, 0.4, { scaleX: '0%', ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7) }, '-=4');
    };
...
```

This may not be exactly the type of animation you wanted but you'll need to adjust the `position` parameter in most/all of your tweens as per your liking but I think the main take away for you would be the use of `cycle` with `delay`.

Hope this helps in some way.

P.S. You can pass negative `stagger` values but they have a different meaning. It tells the engine to start the *staggered* animation from the last element.

Comment: That seems to have it! I am not going to pretend I know exactly what is going on here but this has put me down the right path. This is my first time using Greensock, have to say, loving it so far!